# Как собирать статистику

Tags: mysql

Есть боевая база. Задача в том, чтобы снимать статистику с 3 таблиц (с реплики конечно же)  с периодичностью в 20 минут.
Идея была такая: бекап 3 таблиц - заливаем в новую бд и вызываем use, собираем статистику. 
 Может есть более лучший вариант?

Comment: зачем лучше? делайте то что проще вам.

Comment: Немного не понятен вопрос.Можно создать четвертую (Можно с `engine View` типа) таблицу на основе ` INSERT ... SELECT` из трех ваших.И работать с ней. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: У меня загвоздка в том:
#!/bin/sh
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M`
mysql -u root -p -e 'create database.${DATE}' 
Не могу создать базу с тем временем, с которым создал таблицы.